# how to save graphael linechart() as an image using javascript?

Tags: graphael

I am quite new to graphael js. I want to know if the linechart can be saved as an image programatically using javascript?

I am using canvg to save svg as image

```
var svg = $('#curve').html();
alert(svg);
canvg('canvas', svg);

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
console.log(img);
$('body').append('<img src="'+img+'"/>');
```

where curve is the id of the chart which I want to take the snapshot of. But this gave me the following error in canvg.js:

ERROR: Element 'html' not yet implemented.